# How to implement multi-valued iterator pattern in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have an iterator-type-object that can return zero, one or more items each time it's called. I want to implement a standard `Iter` API, i.e. `next` returns `Option<Self::Item>`, so it can be consumed item by item.

In Clojure I would probably do this with `mapcat` ("map and concatenate").

My current solution (thanks to @Ryan) uses `flat_map` but still requires a lot of allocation:

```
// Desired input:
// A stateful object that implements an iterator which returns a number of results each time.
// The real code is a bit more complicated, this is the minimal example.
struct MyThing {
    counter: i32,
}

impl Iterator for MyThing {
    type Item = Vec<String>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Vec<String>> {
        self.counter += 1;
        if self.counter == 4 {
            self.counter = 1;
        }

        match self.counter {
            1 => Some(vec!["One".to_string()]),
            2 => Some(vec!["One".to_string(), "Two".to_string()]),
            3 => Some(vec![
                "One".to_string(),
                "Two".to_string(),
                "Three".to_string(),
            ]),
            _ => Some(vec![]),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let things = MyThing { counter: 0 };

    // Missing piece, though the following line does the job:
    let flattened = things.flat_map(|x| x);

    // However this requires a heap allocation at each loop.

    // Desired output: I can iterate, item by item.
    for item in flattened {
        println!("{:?}", item);
    }
}
```

Given the innovative things I have seen, I wonder if there's a more idiomatic, less expensive way of accomplishing this pattern.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to further explain (a) what exactly your "iterator-type-object" returns, (b) why `Iterator::flat_map` isn't sufficient, (c) what you mean by "small buffering iterator".

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map?

Comment: Thanks! It's a sequence of lexer tokens (if that makes any difference). `flat_map` looks like it could be what I'm trying to describe.

Comment: Your *question* states that you want to "implement a multi-valued iterator", but that doesn't make any sense to me. You state that you *already* have an "iterator-type-object", so why are you asking about how to implement it?

Comment: By "I want to implement" I mean "I want to express this idiom in Rust". I'm sorry if the title could be pithier. I can currently only see how to do this by allocating a Vec on the heap at each cycle. From what I've learned about Rust so far, I wouldn't be surprised to find there's a better way.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want. What's your input, what's the desired output? Which intermediate operations do you expect to be available to map between those two? Maybe pseudocode?

Comment: The desired input is an object that can return one or more T items each time it is called. The desired output is something that provides `next()`,  returning one item at a time, per the `Iter` trait. I will try and add some code to the question.

Comment: I've added an example, informed by @Ryan above. This may well be the best way to do it.

Comment: The example allocates because the iterator itself allocates. If you have an iterator that doesn't allocate, calling `.flat_map()` on it won't cause it to.

Comment: Ok, so how could I implement the same behaviour (i.e. return an arbitrary number of items) without heap allocation?

Comment: In your real implementation, where are these items coming from? You could avoid the `Vec`s by maintaining a second counter to track which number, but without a representative example if is hard to say what applies to your real code.

Comment: *return an arbitrary number of items without heap allocation* — why do you believe that such a thing is even possible?

Comment: @Shepmaster - The reason I'm asking a question is because I don't know the answer. The reason I'm asking a question at a general patterns, not bits-and-bytes, level because Rust provides different abstractions to languages I'm familiar with and there might be another one I don't know about. This thread has helped me frame my problem, and I'm grateful for the help.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - It's a lexer that can return a number of tokens at each step.  I thought it would be easier to include a running code example and concentrate on the abstraction than yank bits out of the real code with no context.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to generate the "inner" values programmatically, replace `Vec<String>` with a struct you define that implements `Iterator<Item = String>`. (Technically only `IntoIterator` is necessary, but `Iterator` is sufficient.)

```
struct Inner {
    index: usize,
    stop: usize,
}

impl Inner {
    fn new(n: usize) -> Self {
        Inner { index: 0, stop: n }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Inner {
    type Item = String;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<String> {
        static WORDS: [&str; 3] = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
        let result = if self.index < self.stop {
            WORDS.get(self.index).map(|r| r.to_string())
        } else {
            None
        };
        self.index += 1;
        result
    }
}
```

Because `Inner` implements `Iterator<Item = String>`, it can be iterated over much like `Vec<String>`. But `Inner` does not have to pre-allocate a `Vec` and consume items one by one; it can lazily create each `String` on demand.

The "outer" iterator is just a struct that implements `Iterator<Item = Inner>`, likewise constructing each `Inner` lazily:

```
struct Outer {
    counter: i32,
}

impl Iterator for Outer {
    type Item = Inner;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Inner> {
        self.counter = 1 + self.counter % 3;

        Some(Inner::new(self.counter as usize))
    }
}
```

As you know, [`Iterator::flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) flattens nested structure, so something like the following [works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=718afa38be294c4228b05ee42845ea35&version=stable):

```
let things = Outer { counter: 0 };

for item in things.flat_map(|x| x).take(100) {
    println!("{:?}", item);
}
```

In real-life code, `Inner` and `Outer` are probably pretty different from this example most of the time. For example, it's not necessarily possible to write `Inner` without doing the equivalent of allocating a `Vec`. So the precise shapes and semantics of these iterators depend on concrete information about the use case.

---

The above assumes that `Inner` is somehow useful, or easier to implement on its own. You could easily write a single struct that iterates over the sequence without needing to be flattened, but you have to also put the inner iterator state (the `index` field) into `Outer`:

```
struct Outer {
    index: usize,
    counter: i32,
}

impl Iterator for Outer {
    type Item = String;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<String> {
        static WORDS: [&str; 3] = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
        let result = WORDS.get(self.index).map(|r| r.to_string());
        self.index += 1;
        if self.index >= self.counter as usize {
            self.counter = 1 + self.counter % 3;
            self.index = 0;
        };
        result
    }
}

fn main() {
    let things = Outer { counter: 1, index: 0 };

    for item in things.take(100) {
        println!("{:?}", item);
    }
}
```